# Three.js | Raycasting imported .obj model via blender

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have loaded a 3D terrain via Blender with the `OBJLoader`. I have also created a mesh (yellow pointer on the picture below) which i want to follow the mouse while it's on the terrain.
I tried to use the raycaster method but i don't know exactly how to apply it to my .obj as it seems that I can't access it outside the loader.

How can i make my pointer(yellow mesh) stick to my terrain (loaded .obj) while it's following the mouse ?

Please help a total three.js noob...

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 150;
camera.position.y=300;
camera.position.x=350;

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1 );
scene.add( light );

var controls= new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping=true;
controls.campingFactor=0.25;
controls.enableZoom=true;

controls.minDistance= 1;
controls.maxDistance=3000;

controls.minPolarAngle= -Math.PI/2;
controls.maxPolarAngle= Math.PI/2;

var terrain;
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load('models/terrain.mtl',
    (materials) => {
        materials.preload();
    
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.setMaterials(materials);
        loader.load(
                'models/terrain.obj',
        function ( object ) {
        terrain = object;
        scene.add( terrain );
        });
    }
); 


var Cylindergeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 0, 8, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( Cylindergeometry, material );
  
var Torusgeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 7, 0.5, 8, 6);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var torus = new THREE.Mesh( Torusgeometry, material);
Torusgeometry.rotateX(1.5708);
Torusgeometry.translate(0,-4.5,0);
  //Merge the two parts to make it one mesh (yellow pivot)
var PivotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
PivotGeometry.merge(Cylindergeometry);
PivotGeometry.merge(Torusgeometry);
var pivot = new THREE.Mesh(PivotGeometry, material);
scene.add(pivot);  



// Trying to Raycast the terrain to make the pivot follow the mouse while it's on it 
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove( event ) {

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    // See if the ray from the camera into the world hits one of our meshes
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( terrain,true );

    // Toggle rotation bool for meshes that we clicked
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        
        pivot.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
        pivot.lookAt( intersects[ 0 ].face.normal );

        pivot.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );

    }

}

//Met à jour l'affichage de la scène
var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}; 

animate();
```

[My loaded .obj terrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzi1F.jpg)

Comment: I suggest you use the code from: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast

Comment: I already saw this example but they use another type of model which is not .obj, so i'm a little bit lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line in your code:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( object );
```

I don't see where `object` as a variable is declared. I suggest you declare this variable in your module scope, assign the loaded OBJ file to it and then use this code instead:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( object, true );
```

`OBJLoader.load()` returns an object of type `THREE.Group` which is in some sense a container holding an arbitrary number of meshes. Hence, you want to raycast recursively.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i read the Object3D documentation, i assigned the .obj to a variable and then i could finally access to my loaded object via an array of its children.